# Accessing a dictionary using a key from another dictionary in Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am passing two dictionaries to a Django template (**reservations** , **prices**) inside the template i have something like this:

```
{% for key,value in reservations.items %}
...
...
{% if value is False %}
        <div class="room">
            <p class="room-id">{{ prices.{{ key }} }}</p>
         </div>
{% else %}
...
...
{% endfor %}
```

now the problem is this line **{{ prices.{{ key }} }}** i am trying to evaluate the **key** value from the reservations dict to be used in the 
prices dict how this can be done? and thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time,no

Comment: did not try, but just `{{ prices.key }}` should work... and please only post code that can be copy-pasted and tested: especially also post an example input dictionary. see [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice,{{ prices.key }} trys to find key attribute in prices dict.

Comment: again: post the input dictionaries as well: otherwise it's hard do tell what the problem is.

Comment: The {{ prices.{{ key }} }}  will not work.  You need to pass the key like {{price.0}}.

Comment: hiro protagonist let's say:

reservations={'room_1': False, 'room_3': False, 'room_4': False, 'room_5': False, 'room_6': False}

prices={'room_6': '80.0', 'room_4': '120.0', 'room_5': '80.0', 'room_3': '120.0', 'room_1': '140.0'}

Comment: Create a template tags maybe? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks Bast yes that was i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with custom template tags, for example:

```
# access_tags.py

from django import template        

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='access')    
def access(value, arg):    
    return value.get(arg, value.get(unicode(arg), None))
```

and in template:

```
{% load access_tags %}
...
<p class="room-id">{{ prices|access:key }}</p>
...
```

Comment: ndpu Thank you very much it was exactly what i needed